# How to go back to the previous page, but not counting the url variables in the js

Tags: javascript, php, url

I want to go back using something like `window.history.back()`, but I'm generating urls **with variables** in php, like:

[https://www.amazon.com/Legend-Zelda-Breath-Wild-Nintendo-Switch/dp/B01MS6MO77/ref=br_asw_pdt-4?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r=M6RDNMRTP3QXJFK6JR12&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=f8585743-c043-4665-80a7-0cc5fe97d596&pf_rd_i=desktop](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MS6MO77)

You can see the variables after the ?, which itself is after the 4.

If I went to that page **without** the variables, it would look like:

[https://www.amazon.com/Legend-Zelda-Breath-Wild-Nintendo-Switch/dp/B01MS6MO77/ref=br_asw_pdt-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MS6MO77)

So after going to the page **with** url variables **from** the ulr **without** variables, if I click in the button with `window.history.back()`, It will take me back to the same page with the same url but without the variables.

How can I prevent this? I want to go back but ignore similar urls (even if they're different just because of the variables).

Is there any function like: `window.history.ignoreUrlVariables()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function built into the history API but you can implement one yourself.

You can go back multiple pages with `window.history.go(-10)` (back 10 pages).

With this in mind if you add to a counter every time that you alter the URL variables then when you finally want to go back simply call `window.history.go(-counter)` which will take you back to the page before you started editing the URL.